# Ubuntu - compare original package and installed parameters

Tags: ubuntu, installation, aptitude, dpkg

I'd like to compare the actual config files for, say, Apache and the ones provided in the original package.

The purpose is to have a list of modifications since initial installation because I didn't document them originally.

I've cruised along dpkg man pages with no success.

Comment: a similar question was [answered on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16917/17047#17047)

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg` does not store the original copies of the config files separately, but you could download the .deb file and extract it to a temporary area with `dpkg-deb`, for example

```
$ dpkg-deb -x filename.deb /tmp
```

then compare the original versions in the unpacked tree under `/tmp` with the versions installed on the system, perhaps using a tool like `diff`.

Comment: thxs I'll give it a try

By the way, is there a way to do this with aptitude instead of the .deb package?

Comment: @Olivier: you can use `aptitude download <packagename>` to download the .deb file into the current directory automatically. You still need to unpack it though.

Comment: yes I had this idea too but nothing automatic I'm afraid

Thxs anyway